# react-native: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigator.push')

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

**-----Notice my edit at the end!-----**

I just started with react-native and I'm having problems with navigtor.

(I used this example as a template: https://github.com/h87kg/NavigatorDemo)

The first screen (Main) works fine, but when trying to .push to the next it gives me the following error:

**undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigator.push')**

Main:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <Navigator
        style={styles.container}
        initialRoute={{ name: 'Main' }}
        renderScene={ this.renderScene.bind(this) }
      />
    );
  }

  renderScene = (route, navigator) => {
    if(route.name == 'Main') {
     return (
       <TouchableHighlight onPress={ () => this._navigate() }>
         <Text>GO To View</Text>
       </TouchableHighlight>
     );
    }
    if(route.name == 'Home') {
      return <Home navigator={navigator} />
    }
  }

  _navigate = () => {
    this.props.navigator.push({
      name: 'Home',
    })
  }
```

Home just displays some Text in its renderScene:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <Navigator
        renderScene={ this.renderScene.bind(this) }
        navigator={this.props.navigator}
      />
    );
  }

  renderScene(route, navigator){
    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>
          2nd Screen!
        </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
```

Edit: I've tried `this._navigate().bind(this)`, but still not working

**So, `this.props.navigator` is never defined, but how and where do I define it?**

Comment: Have you tried checking whether the `navigator` exists and what methods does it have? Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props.navigator)` right before calling `push()`.

Comment: nope, the log says it's undefined, but why?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can not reference your navigator from your callback function is because the action was generated from another context different than your current component.

I was facing a similar problem using a **FlatList** Component. I'll let an example for those that may face this problem in the future.

```
export default class AlertsScreen extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        alertTypes: [{ key: 'type1', name: 'Alert 1'}, { key: 'type2', name: 'Alert 2'}],
    }
    navigator = this.props.navigator;
}

_onAlertTypePressed(typeId: string, typeName: string){
    navigator.push({
        screen: 'foo.bar.AlertsCreator',
        title: 'Alert',
        passProps: { alertId: typeId }
});

}
```

In the example above, I get a reference from the navigator object, and then use it to push a new screen when the user taps an item from the **FlatList**.

**NOTE**: Using [Wix/React-native-navigation](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/)

Answer (score 0):

Try binding the `_navigate` method to the correct object context in the `constructor` of the class:

```
class myComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this._navigate = this._navigate.bind(this);
  }

  // NOTE body ...
};
```

Comment: still the same error (had to add super(); before the allocation)